# Can the tags concerning images be improved?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are currently seven tags on Software Recommendations that start with `image`:

[image]

I couldn't help but notice the following points:

- [image-conversion](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-conversion) falls within the description of [image-processing](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing), which one could use along with the existing [media-conversion](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/media-conversion) tag to get the same point across.
- [image-editing](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-editing) is confusing, and it is used in different places to mean different things. Some questions associate it with processing, and others with editors
- [images](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/images) seems too generic and its description intersects with that of [image-processing](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing)

Are these tags optimal, or can they be improved in any way?

Answer (score 2):

Suggestions:

- Get rid of [image-conversion](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-conversion), and re-tag its seven questions into [image-processing](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing) and/or [media-conversion](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/media-conversion) as fit for each one
- Get rid of [image-editing](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-editing), and re-tag its nine questions into [image-processing](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing) or [image-editor](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-editor) as fit for each one
- <s>Rename [images](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/images) into something more specific and distinct such as [image-management](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-management), and restrict its use for sorting, storing, and managing images, while excluding editing and conversion as those should be parts of [image-processing](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing)</s> (edited after the discussion in comments)

  - A generic [images](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/images) tag is useful for questions that are outside the scope of the other specifc tags. Its tag description could be changed to exlude conversion and processing.

Comment: When we're on it, we might as well see to "unify" the naming. Example from your suggestion: We'd end up with e.g. `image-processing` and `image-editor`. Shouldn't we rather end up with either `image-processing` and `image-editing` – or `image-processor` and `image-editor` (i.e. either verb or noun, no mixes)?

Comment: Dot-1: We should consider making `image-converion` a synonym after that – or we'd have it back as tag pretty soon. Similar for dot-2 in case the target will not be `image-edit*`. Dot-3 leaves me thinking if there shouldn't be a "general tag for image-related questions not fitting elsewhere". Apart from that I second your suggestion to "reduce redundancy".

Comment: @Izzy True. There are also generic tags for video, music, etc... and there will most likely still be questions that won't fit under either `management` or `processing`. Also, I suppose one could also use `images` + `file-management` to specifiy storage and sorting in particular. I'll strike the third point

Comment: Yupp, then I'll give it a thumbs-up meanwhile – though "unification" is still left open; but that might be done in another task, as after all those tags are already there curently. Apart from that, I'm still struggling with the term – as "images" (especially with file-management) could also mean "disk images"/"partition images" – but well, that's what tag excerpts are for (but who reads them I wonder)...

Comment: @Izzy Re: first comment. `Editing` and `processing` are also nouns, albeit in different forms. Would it be more sensible to have `image-editor` and `image-processor` as synonyms to `image-editing` and `image-processing`, respectively?

Comment: As synonym to an existing similar form they make no sense (the synonym-suggestion in my second comment rather targets those who start typing "image-conv*", so they get automatically redirected via that synonym). What I was pointing at was to have consistant forms – not e.g. using "*-editor" here and "*-editing" there.

Comment: @Izzy I think that, like you mentioned, this should be another discussion. It's not only related to images. For example, we have `text-editors`, `html-editor`, `audio-editing`, and `video-editing` tags which also aren't consistent in form

Comment: And here you go: [Unify tag names](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1128/185)